# Json with .NET and C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, .net

I'm having trouble parsing Json string to Objects in C#. I'm using this:

```
JavaScriptSerilizer parser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

but it doesn't recognize the JavaScriptSerilizer, and I can't add this:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

but it returns an error, not recognizing the "Script" in "System.Web", and I added "System.Web" in the References. Also, I found "System.Web.Extensions.dll" in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\", added it as a Reference but I get this error:

```
Could not resolve assembly "System.Web.Extensions". The assembly is not in the currently targetet framework...
```

I searched for the same file in lower version but I couldn't find it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is implemented in `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, not in `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: Could not resolve assembly "System.Web.Extensions". The assembly is not in the currently targetet framework...

Comment: @GregaMenih: `JavaScriptSerializer` is available in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4, and *not in .NET 4 Client Profile*. You will have to [change your target framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` in your project.

[MSDN: JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

If you look at the MSDN documentation for a class, it tells you which assembly it's in at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please add reference to System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll) in your project.